# Sort dictionary elements in list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

For this list,

```
[{u'status': u'Active', u'name': u'X', u'orgID': u'109175', u'type': u'Created Section','class': 'addbold'} , 
{u'status': u'Active', u'name': u'A', u'orgID': u'109175', u'type': u'Created Section', 'class': 'addbold'} ,
{u'status': u'Active', u'name': u'G', u'orgID': u'109175', u'type': u'Created Section', 'class': 'addbold'} ,
{u'status': u'Active', u'name': u'D', u'orgID': u'109175', u'type': u'Created Section', 'class': 'addbold'}]
```

I want to arrange the list items in alphabetic order based on name key of dictionary.

So output would be like this,

```
[{u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'A', 'class': 'addbold'} ,
{u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'D', 'class': 'addbold'} ,
{u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'G', 'class': 'addbold'} , 
{u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'X', 'class': 'addbold'}]
```

How can I sort list dict items in this list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) or [`list.sort`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) accept optional `key` function parameter. The return value of the function is used to compare elements order.

```
>>> lst = [...]
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x['name'])
[{u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'A', 'class': 'addbold'},
 {u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'D', 'class': 'addbold'},
 {u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'G', 'class': 'addbold'},
 {u'status': u'Active', u'type': u'Created Section', u'orgID': u'109175', u'name': u'X', 'class': 'addbold'}]
```

[`operator.itemgetter('name')`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) can be used in place of the `lambda` function.

```
import operator
sorted(lst, key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
```